# What are the solutions to this nonlinear equation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

Besides the constant solutions what are the solutions to:

$\dot{u}=u \Delta u$

where $u_0$ is defined on a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Some further information would be useful. Do you want a classical solution or a weak solution? BC are $u\equiv 0$ on $\partial\Omega$  I guess? Is $u_0=u\vert_{t=0}$ continuous?

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comment, some additional information would help answering the question. Assuming standard hypotheses, the problem you are interested in can be considered as a degenerate case of the problem $\dot{u}=u^s\Delta u,\ 0<s<1$, which is related, via $x=(1-s)^{\frac{1-s}{s}}u^{1-s}$ and $n=\frac{1}{1-s}$, to the porous medium diffusion equation $\dot{x}=\Delta x^n$.

If you are interested in weak solutions, the following papers can be useful: [M.Winkler, 2004](https://www.openstarts.units.it/bitstream/10077/4163/1/WinklerRendMat36.pdf), [R. Dal Passo, 1987](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82273256.pdf). The second one concerns your problem (if you assume there $g\equiv 0$), while in the first one $u\Delta$ is replaced by a more general nonlinear term of type $f(u)\Delta u$, with technical assumptions on $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the references, what is known in the case $\Omega$ is a closed manifold? What is the long-time behavior?